# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'API_KEY' of 'dotenv.parsed' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, vercel

```
[webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'API_KEY' of 'dotenv.parsed' as it is undefined.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/webpack/config.dev.js:7:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/webpack/config.build.js:10:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 2
```

i have put `environment variables` in vercel, when i deploy the project to vercel that occur the problem. how to fix that